# vba to create and save a function in another file

Tags: excel, vba

i have this excel macro in a file that calls a text file and converts it into excel then saves the new excel file to a specific location. each time I run the macro a new excel file will be created. however, I want this macro to add some functions inside this file in a specific sheet before saving it to the new directory and next time I open the new excel file the function should be running normally and if i go to the vba window i should see my function there.

1- i run the macro from my macro file
2- it opens my new excel and adds a function inside sheet1 and saves the excel file in it's new directory

any ideas on how to do that ?

thanks and best regards

Comment: What did you try on your own? At least, the code you mentioned should be added, I would say...

Comment: instead of creating a new sheet before saving, are you able to copy a blank workbook, with the functions already defined, and place the text file contents in that sheet/workbook. kind of like a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It creates a new workbook (you may use the one you obtained opening the text file), inserts a standard module (named "TestModule"), creates a `Sub` ("WrittenFromAnotherWorbook") and then creates the same test `Sub` in the "Sheet1" module. The new saved workbook ("TestWorkbookWithCode.xlsm") can be found in the same path with the workbook keeping this code:

```
Sub CreateNewWorkbookAddMacro()
   'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3'
   Dim wb As Workbook, project As VBProject, component As VBComponent
   Dim code(1 To 3) As String, i As Long, boolFound As Boolean
   Const moduleName As String = "TestModule"
   
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   Set project = wb.VBProject
   code(1) = "Sub WrittenFromAnotherWorbook()"
   code(2) = "    MsgBox ""Hello from the new workbook!"""
   code(3) = "End Sub"
   
    For Each component In project.VBComponents
        'if the module has already been created, exit the code:
        If component.Name = moduleName Then boolFound = True: Exit For
    Next
    If Not boolFound Then
        Set component = project.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
        component.Name = moduleName
        'Put the code in place:
        For i = LBound(code) To UBound(code)
            component.CodeModule.InsertLines i, code(i)
        Next
    End If
    Set component = project.VBComponents(wb.Worksheets(1).CodeName)
    'Put the (same) code in place:
    For i = LBound(code) To UBound(code)
        component.CodeModule.InsertLines i, code(i)
    Next
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestWorkbookWithCode.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

If you are not familiar with references adding, please use the next code to programmatically add the needed one:

```
Sub addExtenssibilityReference()
   'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibilty 5.3':
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3
End Sub
```

You must firstly run this code, save your workbook keeping the code and then run the one able to do what I explained above.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @kamal_hamad: Didn't you find some time to test the above recommended solution? If tested, didn't it behave as you need? Something unclear with the above code(s)?

Comment: thank you I really appreciate it, it did work pretty well. I just didn't have enough time to test it till now and it did work amazingly with no errors